# How can I display these values with spaces to separate the words?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I'll `console.log(JSON.stringify(selected["1"]?.others))`, this is what it shows:

```
["Cars","Books","Necklaces"]
```

However, displaying this in the screen, this will display all of the data, however, there are no spaces between each words. It shows like this

> CarsBooksNecklaces

the `others` in `selected["1"]?.others` is an array.

This is what it looks like in firestore:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an array of string values you could use `join` method like this:

```js
selected["1"]?.others.join(' ')
```

Comment: Masksimovic I tried entering a `<br/>` in the parameters of `join`, it'll just show `[object]`

Comment: @RavenousRed Assuming you are using React, if you want to create a new line between the elements with `<br />` then just iterate over the array like this:

`{selected['1']?.others.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item} <br /></div>)}`
but I would advise against using `<br />`, it would be much better just to render `ul` with an `li` for each item in `others` array.